# Incompatible type parameter in lambda expression

Tags: java, javafx

`ChangeListener` has a method `changed()` with the signature

```
void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue);
```

But when i tried to do the following it says "incompatible type parameter in lambda expression".

```
ChangeListener listener1;
listener1 = (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue , Number number, Number number2) -> 

{ textareaDescription.setText((String) options1.get(number2.intValue())); textareaMustCheck.setText((String) options2.get(number2.intValue())); };
```

however follwoing code works perfectly

```
 choiceboxStrategy.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number2) -> {
            textareaDescription.setText((String) options1.get(number2.intValue()));
            textareaMustCheck.setText((String) options2.get(number2.intValue()));
```

Comment: Isnt it suppose to be `=>` then `->` ?

Comment: Corrected, but still doesn't work @Henry

Comment: I think we need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I don't know how `ObservableValue` or `ChangeListener` are defined, but if I try using other classes instead I don't get an error.  So I think we need more info.

Comment: `ChangeListener` takes a parameter, but you didn't specify one in the declaration (ex. `ChangeListener<Number> listener1`).

Comment: @MikaelF What `ChangeListener` takes a type parameter?  [This one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) doesn't.  We weren't given enough info about what classes he's using, so maybe there's another `ChangeListener` that does--but do we have enough info to guess?

Comment: Sorry, voted to reopen because there's not enough info in the question to know whether this is a raw type issue.

Comment: @ajb Not sure why you say that. It's easily reproduced and easily fixed by adding the type parameter.

Comment: @ajb [This one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) (from JavaFX) does, and I'm pretty sure that's the one OP's using (it has a `changed()` method).

Comment: @shmosel It can only be reproduced if you happen to know where these classes are.  There is nothing in the question that indicates that this is JavaFX.  The classes aren't in the normal Java 8 javadoc.  This makes it not only impossible to answer if you aren't real familiar with JavaFX, it also makes it impossible to know that it involves knowledge I don't know about.

Comment: @shmosel the `ChangeListener` in JavaFX takes a type parameter; the one in Swing doesn't, and it wasn't specified in the tags which of the two OP was using.

Comment: @shmosel Given that I eventually figured out what was going on, it's OK with me to close as a duplicate.  But there really needs to be more information in the question.  Even a "javafx" tag would have helped.

Comment: It's clear from the method signature that it's from JavaFX. I'm not familiar with the class myself, but it wasn't hard to figure out.

Comment: @shmosel how is it clear from the method signature???  If you've used JavaFX a lot, then it's clear.  If one is not familiar with it, then there's no way to tell.  There's no way to tell that it isn't a class they wrote themselves.  Anyway, I've added the javafx tag to avoid anyone else being confused.

Comment: to avoid any confusion yes its javafx. help me out guys. For testing purpose you can put any simple code inside lambda block @shmosel

Comment: Your question was answered by [@MikaelF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618178/incompatible-type-parameter-in-lambda-expression?noredirect=1#comment72365467_42618178).

Comment: I don't think it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is quite simple. Your Lambda expression is wrong. Replace it with this version:

```
    ChangeListener<Number> listener1;

    listener1 = (observableValue , number, number2) -> 

    { textareaDescription.setText((String) options1.get(number2.intValue())); textareaMustCheck.setText((String) options2.get(number2.intValue())); };
```

You used ChangeListener as a raw type.

Added:

This is a shortened version of your listener which compiles without errors:

```
    ChangeListener<Number> listener1 = (v, o, n) -> {int i2 = n.intValue();};
```

If you still see errors then they are caused by your other code which you haven't shown us and so we can't say anything about it.

Comment: Still showing error in intValue()

Comment: See my shortened version.